# Opening a website frame or image in python

Tags: python, cookies, browser, urllib2

So i am fairly fluent with python and have used urllib2 and Cookies a lot for website automation. I just stumbled upon the "webbrowser" module which can open a url in your default browser. Im wondering if its possible to select just one object from that url and open that up. Specifically i want to open a "captcha" so that the user can input it, and continue doing something else.

this is line containing the captcha in the html, i think:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LcZ-AAAAAAAANX-xwVtzow1f4RpSrbSViRUx9Js"></script>    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit"
```

and clicking on that api link opens this:

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    site : '6LcZ-AAAAAAAANX-xwVtzow1f4RpSrbSViRUx9Js',
    challenge : '03AHJ_VuvoUHPdfoXLsVHGa7a26GR9s9Y5dkyKmqk2XsJ1SdiwF_2u0SV_sKnr1artkpc-5MjUe7SYD40xr7sAyvikKwpFCQTBdKUFfl76UP6EbDhezoTC8B1X8fjixuIJ4wJhI6yTc8vlX4ioh6je9lwFbPXllbGh2w',
    is_incorrect : false,
    programming_error : '',
    error_message : '',
    server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    timeout : 18000
};

document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

any info would help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with the webbrowser module. All webbrowser does is provide a simple way to identify the default web browser and feed a URL to it.

If you want to render just a portion of a page, you need something that can either take arbitrary HTML fragments or can inject some Javascript after loading a page to strip out the unwanted elements.

For that, what you need is to build a purpose-specific web browser that's nothing more than a dialog box containing a web widget.

That can be done using any of the following combinations of libraries:

- [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) and the included [QtWebKit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebview.html) (GPL or Commercial, Windows/Mac/Linux)
- [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) and the included [QtWebKit](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebView.html) (LGPL, Linux)
- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) and [PyWebKitGTK](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) (LGPL, Easy on Linux... no clue about Windows or OSX)
- [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) and [GTKMozEmbed](http://exelearning.org/wiki/GtkMozEmbed) (LGPL, Easy on Linux... no clue about Windows or OSX)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) and the included [wxIEHtmlWindow](http://groups.google.com/group/google-apps-apis/browse_thread/thread/eea81678085b8904?pli=1) (BSD-like, Windows-only. Embeds Internet Explorer.)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) and the included [wxWebKitCtrl](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.webkit-module.html) (BSD-like, OSX-only)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) and [wxWebKit](http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/) (BSD-like, Windows/Mac/Linux)

My advice:

- If GPL licensing is OK, use PyQt.
- If GPL licensing isn't OK:

  - For Linux, use PySide or PyGTK with PyWebKitGTK (GTKMozEmbed is heavy)
  - For Windows, use wxPython with wxIEHtmlWindow
  - For OSX, you'll have to ask someone else.